# Zapier polling for new entries

Tags: api, zapier

All,

I have created a standalone webhook that polls an endpoint looking for new entries. The process works as expected the poll picks up all of the newly added items and generates a draft email for each entity.

Since I have created an app on Zapier and tried to replicate this process. When creating the Zap at the "Test this step" point the poll runs and picks up the new entries, however when this is run as a stand alone Zap it doesnt retrieve any data.

Comment: Hey there! That's confusing because the "test this step" is the exact same function behind the scenes as am actual run of the zap. It should work for neither or both. Is there new data that comes back in the poll, but nothing in task history?

Comment: Hi, I have fixed this now the problem was the results contained fields like `paid` and `ispaid` along with the primary key field so Zapier was confused as to which to use. Solved by adding some scripting which loops through the results and adds an `id` property to each object